# Splitting unit and integration tests for android

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, integration-testing

Currently I have a `test/src/java` folder where all of the tests for the android application are stored (tests are done using junit, mockito and robolectric).

And I can run those using `./gradlew test`

What I'd like to achieve is having two folders:

1. `integrationTest/src/java` - for integration tests
2. `test/src/java` - for unit tests

And also I'd like to run them separately, like `./gradlew test` and `./gradlew integrationTest`.

I've managed to split directories with tests using `sourceSets` like this:

```
    sourceSets {
        test {
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src/test/java', 'src/integrationTest/java', 'src/commonTest/java']
            }
            resources {
                srcDirs = ['src/test/resources', 'src/integrationTest/resources', 'src/commonTest/resources']
            }
        }
    }
```

And I had googled many examples on how to create custom test tasks, but most of them are related to java instead of android and the others are out-of-date. I've spent on that the whole day now and so if someone can help me I would really appreciate that.

Comment: This library here: [link](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-android/blob/master/build.gradle) has it working. However it uses the `'com.android.library'` plugin.

Comment: There is a default `androidTest` folder for android tests that will be running on the device/emulator. Is that folder what you need ?

Answer (score 3):

If your integration tests are instrumented tests, then you can just use the default folders `test` and `androidTest` and run them separately using `./gradlew test` and `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`

Another way (if you can have the integration tests inside the `test` folder) would be to use separate packages inside the `test` folder and run the tests separately using:

```
./gradlew testDebug --tests="com.yourapplication.unittests.*"
./gradlew testDebug --tests="com.yourapplication.integrationtests.*"
...
```

Comment: `./gradlew testDebug --tests com.company.package.unittest.*`

See https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html#RunTestsGradle
and 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering

the solution that really works for android app. There are a lot of other samples and solutions, but they are about java projects, not android.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a few days ago.

In order to solve it and be able to run each type of test independently, I separated my tests like this:

```
// run only unit tests
test{
    include '**/unit/**'
    exclude '**/integration/**'
    doLast {
        println 'Unit tests execution finished.'
    }
}

// run only integration tests
task integrationTest(type: Test){
    include '**/integration/**'
    exclude '**/unit/**'
    doLast {
        println 'Integration tests execution finished.'
    }
}

// run all tests (unit + integration)
task allTests(type: Test){
    include '**/integration/**'
    include '**/unit/**'
    doLast {
        println 'All tests execution finished.'
    }
}
```

The **include** keyword indicates which files you want to include when executing the commands. If you want to run *only* your unit tests, you can only include the folder(s) that include your unit tests and exclude the folders that include your integration tests.

You can use a similar logic when creating a gradle command to run *only* your integration tests.

To execute your tests using this configuration and gradle, use:

- `./gradlew test` to execute the unit tests **only**.
- `./gradlew integrationTests` to execute the integration tests **only**.
- `./gradlew allTests`to execute **both** the integration and the unit tests.

**NOTE:** You can setup the paths in the includes / excludes in order to include / exclude tests or classes when executing your tests. It is also possible to include only one test and exclude the others and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output
            srcDir 'src/integrationTest/java'
        }
        resources.srcDir 'src/integrationTest/resources'
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile { 
        extendsFrom compile 
    }
    integrationTestRuntime {
        extendsFrom runtime
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
check.dependsOn integrationTest
```

Then you could do

```
dependencies {
    integrationTestCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1'
    integrationTestRuntime 'com.foo:bar:1.0'
}
```

Comment: That is a java solution, no? Android is a bit different.

Comment: I've tried some variations of this. Not working on android.